# Drawing smoother circles using Core Graphics

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d, geometry

I am creating an app where users draw on a custom view.  I have the basic code done, yet when I draw a circle, the result is a weird 8+ sided polygon.

I have read into using Bezier paths (or something of that nature), yet everything I have seen with Bezier paths involve drawing a shape in code instead of user drawn.

Is there anything to help my messed up circles become smooth circles?

Any help is appreciated, and please specify in comments if you do not understand my situation!
Thanks!

Comment: How are you drawing the circle?  Are you recording points where the users has touched, and drawing a bunch of lines?

Comment: Im using the basic code found in the youtube video for non-destructive drawing.  I basically find the current position of the finger, use cgcontext begin path, move to point and end path.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `CGContextAddEllipseInRect` yet?

(what are you using now?)